# filtro de busqueda de producto

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, filtro, radio

Necesito ayuda estoy intentado hacer un filtro de selección mediante input radio para que al momento de seleccionar un radio por ejemplo "mujer" me aparezcan solo los relojes de mujeres que están almacenados en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es una imagen donde tengo mis productos tengo unos input radio de tres tipos pero al momento de seleccionarlos no me sirve solo me aparcente todos.

```html
<form class="" action="admincatalog.php" method="POST">
        <input type="radio" name="gender_admin" class="data checkboxs" value="Hombre">Hombre
        <input type="radio" name="gender_admin" class="data checkboxs" value="Mujer">Mujer
        <input type="radio" name="gender_admin" class="data checkboxs" value="Bolsillo">Bolsillo<br>
      </form>
      <?php
      require 'conexion.php';
      $genero = $_POST["gender_admin"];
      $selectg="SELECT * FROM products WHERE gender_admin = '$genero'";
      $productg = mysqli_query($conexion,$selectg);
      while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($productg)){
        $idproduct = $row['id_product'];
        $imagen = $row['archivo'];
        $marca = $row['brand_admin'];
        $modelo = $row['model_admin'];
        $catalogo = "
        <html>
        <div class='catalogbox'>
          <div class='' style='display: flex;'>
            <div class='' style='width: 50%;'>
              <img src='".$imagen."' id='imgSalida' style='width: 120px; height: 160px; margin: 10%' alt=''>
            </div>
            <div class='' style='width: 50%;'>
              <strong>Marca:</strong><br>".$marca."<br>
              <strong>Modelo:</strong><br>".$modelo."<br>
              <strong>Pais:</strong><br>".$row['conutry_admin']."<br>
              <b>Año.</b><br>".$row['year_admin']."<br>
              <b>Genero</b><br>".$row['gender_admin']."<br>
              <b>Precio:</b><br>".$row['price_admin']."<br>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='' style>
            <b>Descripcion:</b><br>".$res['description_admin']."<br>
          </div><br>
        </div>
        </html>";
        echo $catalogo;
      }
       ?>
    </div>
```

No estoy seguro si tengo que utilizar el formulario para poder seleccionar las el genero y el php donde mando a llamar la info esta bien puesto que si me muestra el producto solo quiero que funcione el input radio

Comment: ¿Si haces un `var_dump($genero);` qué sale en pantalla? ¿El formulario y el código PHP están en el mismo archivo? ¿Seguro que los datos está diferenciados en la base de datos?

Comment: Para filtrar hay dos opciones, hacerlo por el lado del cliente o por el lado del servidor entregando los datos ya filtrados. ¿Cual es la forma que andas buscando?

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM por el lado del cliente